# how to create uri in bitemporal data ingestion?

Tags: xquery

How does URI in bitemporal data ingestion? Should it be the same URI as the inserted document URI and also how can inserted document be updated?

I tried to ingest 2 documents called `a.xml` and `b.xml` into a collection as bitemporal data. I concatenated the word bitemp with the output URI and got **bitemp/a.xml**.

Now if I want both the documents to be given to a same USI what should be done?

The error here is:

> conflict in ingestion due to for loop.

Comment: Which XQuery processor are you using?

Comment: MarkLogic has a bitemp feature; is that what you're using? If so, please add the "marklogic" tag.

Comment: no that is just a name i gave my folder.